# Dynamically created Webbrowser opens Chrome

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with dynamically created Webbrowser control. I have an array of links that have to be checked (I'm building an application that's testing website's security), and sometimes my application launches my default Browser (Chrome in my case) with some strange URL, or it launches Internet Explorer with a message "Navigation canceled". I noticed that in some cases "Navigation canceled" occurs when parsed URL is not valid, like "http://https://..." but in some cases, URL is perfectly valid and it still fires IE for some reason.

Here's actual code:

```
Private Sub CheckByInnerText()
    Dim WebBrowserCBInnerText As New WebBrowser()
    AddHandler WebBrowserCBInnerText.DocumentCompleted, New _
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf WBInnerText)
    WebBrowserCBInnerText.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

    WebBrowserCBInner.Url = New Uri(WebLinksArray(WebLinksArrayIndex))
End Sub

Private Sub WBInnerText(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim WebBrowserCBInnerText As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
    LinkTB.Text = WebBrowserCBInnerText.Document.Body.InnerText

    'Processing Document InnerText...

     WebBrowserCBInnerText.Dispose()

    NextWebSite()
End Sub
```

For example, www.getcider.com fires Chrome with this link: https://getcider.com/#channel=f26acb506f05db6&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fgetcider.com

Comment: It definitely appears to be related to the dispose.  I'm not sure if you can remove that safely, but if you can, I think that solves the problem.

Comment: Some of the websites you're testing could contain pop-ups

Comment: @nweb101 Disposing of the web browser is called only after execution of "'Processing Document InnerText..." code. But I'll try without disposing of WB and get back here with results. -F0r3v3r-A-N00b is there any way to disable pop-ups in dynamically created Webbrowser?

Comment: It's weird how that dynamically coded Webbrowser doesn't work as it should. I created Webbrowser object, set Timer, and Timeout, now it works like a charm. The only thing is Webbrowser that's hidden somewhere in the form, but that was not what I wanted. However, looks like that dispose() was responsible for that weird behavior, but without it, output was totally incorrect (and I don't know why). However, thank you for replying!